# Ubuntu 14.04 and playing songs from cron

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, cron, environment-variables

I recently upgraded my computer to Ubuntu 14.04.

After the upgrade the system no longer plays the few songs I had it play via crontab.

The crontab lines look like so:

```
0 9   *   *   1-5       /usr/bin/mpg123 -q /home/user/Music/song.mp3
```

I get no error from cron upon running the command. If I run the command manually via SSH the song plays successfully.

I prepended the command in crontab with 'env' to get a better grip of the environment under which cron runs the job:

```
0 9   *   *   1-5       env; /usr/bin/mpg123 /home/user/Music/song.mp3
```

This generated the following output:

```
HOME=/home/user
LOGNAME=user
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/user
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
    version 1.16.0; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
    free software (LGPL) without any warranty but with best wishes

Directory: /home/user/Music/
Playing MPEG stream 1 of 1: song.mp3 ...

MPEG 1.0 layer III, 320 kbit/s, 44100 Hz stereo
Comment:  00000000 00000210 00000AA0 000000000058C5D0 00000000 00506FD7 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

[2:11] Decoding of song.mp3 finished
```

To make the interactive shell of my ssh connection more like the one cron is running under I unset all but the specified environment vaiables:

```
for a in `env | awk -F= '{ print $1 }' | grep -v "HOME\|LOGNAME\|PATH\|LANG\|SHELL\|PWD" | xargs`; do unset $a; done
```

And after that change copy+paste from crontab no longer produce any sound. The program seem to play the file however:

```
$ /usr/bin/mpg123 /home/user/Music/song.mp3
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
        version 1.16.0; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
        free software (LGPL) without any warranty but with best wishes

Directory: /home/user/Music/
Playing MPEG stream 1 of 1: song.mp3 ...

MPEG 1.0 layer III, 128 kbit/s, 44100 Hz joint-stereo

[2:51] Decoding of song.mp3 finished.
```

Leading me to believe that the sound is just output to the wrong device.

Switching to aplay the followning produces no sound:

```
$ aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

But specifying this device does play over HDMI as intended:

```
$ aplay -D plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

How can I set that device as the system default?
(Which it seems to be whenever I have a richer environment.)

Alternatively, how can I force mgp123 to use the correct device?
Does the ALSA-device **plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3** correlate to a device in /dev?

mpg123 will let you specify a particular device like so:

```
   -a dev, --audiodevice dev
          Specify the audio device to use.  The default is system-dependent (usually /dev/audio or /dev/dsp).  Use this option if  you  have  multiple  audio
          devices and the default is not what you want.
```

The plughw devices in alsa:

```
$ aplay -L | grep plughw -A2
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC889A Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, ALC889A Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Seem to match up with the pcmC0D?p-devices in /dev/snd:

```
$ ls /dev/snd/ | egrep [013]p
pcmC0D0p
pcmC0D1p
pcmC0D3p
```

But using it does not seem to help mpg123:

```
$ /usr/bin/mpg123 -q -a /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p /home/user/Music/song.mp3
[oss.c:129] error: Can't reset audio!
[mpg123.c:690] error: ...in decoding next frame: Unable to set up output format! (code 1)
```

I don't really understand what ALSA and/or PulseAudio is in respect to this.

Neither seem to work in the limited environment:

```
$ pactl list cards
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
$ alsamixer
Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

Both commands work with "normal" environment variables set.

I downloaded and ran alsa-info.sh, first with "normal" environment:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=e2be8ceb9ef289ff9ef95557396dd82b88f337e0

When I tried to run it with most environment variable unset I got an error.

After setting:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

I got the script running again. Result here:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=67fdd80bd55c76cd6dd30c981bf02fe66ba3d9d6

EDIT:

Further investigation of environment variable unsetting shows that I only have to unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR to break playback.

```
$ unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

EDIT2:

If I abandon mgp123 for cvlc I get sound when playing via crontab like so:

```
 0 9  *   *    1-5      /usr/bin/cvlc -q --alsa-audio-device="hw:0,3" --play-and-exit /home/user/Music/song.mp3 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: - From aplay -L , the working device when you test with  aplay  is  HDMI audio output (CARD=NVidia,DEV=3  HDA NVidia, HDMI 0) : do you really use HDMI display audio output and not normal jack output ? For alsamixer error, do you use ssh connection or local terminal ?      Can you  run "Alsa-info" to show your audio config (someone can have an idea) : copy the following command in a terminal , choose "upload" option when asked ("tab" key to select it) an post url printed at the end.
`wget http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh -O alsa-info.sh && bash alsa-info.sh`

Comment: Yes, it is my intention to play sound over HDMI. I'm connecting to the machine using SSH.

Comment: I've run and uploaded the output of alsa-info.sh. Links in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At As you use ssh connection , try to add your user in the "audio" group  :
`sudo  usermod -aG audio username`
reboot and test  that alsamixer is ok , so you can set volumes: Probably you have to press F6 to select the 3rd device.

Then,in my case, I can read  sound connected by ssh on a remote pc without X server  using:

- cvlc ( which comes with vlc-nox package):
  `cvlc --alsa-audio-device="hw:0,3" /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`
  If not ok, change hw:0,3 to hw:0,0  or hw:0,1
  In my case,  it works also via crontab.
- mpg123:  this works also launched via ssh:
  `mpg123 -a hw:0,3 Musique/test.mp3`

Note that in my case, pulseaudio is disable on the remote pc (not sure disabling is useful  as pulseaudio is started thru X and  lightdm session  ).  To verify that pulseaudio is off and not auto respawning, run various times `killall -9 pulseaudio`

Comment: user is already in audio group. changing to cvlc works, but seems like overkill?

Comment: it depends what format you want to play,but i edited the answers: works also with mpg123

Answer (score 7):

So, I just set the environment variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` the same as in my working shells, and it works.  I found this page because I had this **same** issue with trying to get sound to play from cron jobs -- mpg123 seeming to think it plays the file fine, but with no audio. Setting that variable fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! The cron installed on my system was happy to let me just dump `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/<my $UID>` on a line in `crontab` (this won't work everywhere unfortunately)

Answer (score 4):

Despite using this export:

```
# paplay needs environment variable exported:
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
```

it didn't work.

After months of research found no solution.

In desperation, tried the following and it worked:

**Enter the following in contab**

```
# Terminal command: crontab -e
# Detect the name of the display in use
display=":$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/* | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"
user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}') # the user of the display 
uid=$(id -u $user) #Detect the id of the user

XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/${uid}

*/5 * * * * sh /root/.play_sound.sh
```

Next create `.play_sound.sh`

**/root/.play_sound.sh**

```
display=":$(ls /tmp/.X11-unix/* | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"
user=$(who | grep '('$display')' | awk '{print $1}') # the user of the display 
uid=$(id -u $user) #Detect the id of the user

su - $user -c "paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Been years since I left that system behind, so I can’t really verify your findings, but your write up looks good. Thanks for keeping the topic alive.

Comment: I had more or less the same problem as OP, but setting `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` in crontab was sufficient to make sound work.